# Solving Second-Order partial derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ in $ξ = x +ay$, $η = x +by$ such that they transform the partial differential
equation :

$$ \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + 4\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x\partial y}\right) + 3\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\right) =0$$

into

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial ξ\partial η} = 0$$

I'm aware how to solve simpler derivatives like $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} $ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ but I dont understand how to do the $\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}\right)$ derivatives.

I'd appreciate if someone could show me the process.

Comment: I don't really understand this through words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can expand partial derivatives w.r.t. $x,y$ in terms of $\xi,\eta$ using the chain rule.

$$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{d\partial xi}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}$$

$$\frac {\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y}=a\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}+b\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}$$

We can also expand second partials the same way. Since we've made no assumptions about $u$, we can substitute any function we want (including our expansion of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$) in its place. We can assume the mixed partials are equal in this case.

$$\frac {\partial ^2u}{\partial x^2}=\frac \partial {\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)$$

$$=\frac \partial {\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\right)$$

$$=\frac \partial {\partial \xi}\left(\frac{d\partial }{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\right)+\frac \partial {\partial \eta}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\right)$$

$$=\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi^2}+2\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}+\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \eta^2}$$

Performing the same computations for the other second partials gives:

$$\frac {\partial ^2u}{\partial y^2}=a^2\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi^2}+2ab\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}+b^2\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \eta^2}$$

$$\frac {\partial ^2u}{\partial x\partial y}=a\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi^2}+(a+b)\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}+b\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \eta^2}$$

Plugging these into the DE gives:

$$(1+4a+3a^2)\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi^2}+(2+4a+4b+6ab)\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}+(1+4b+b^2)\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \eta^2}=0$$

Here we want the 1st and 3rd coefficients to be $0$, which gives us $a=-1,-3$ and $b=-1,-3$. However, notice that the $\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}$ coefficient will be zero if we choose the same value for $a$ and $b$. This means we should choose $a=-1,\ b=-3$.

($a=-3,\ b=-1$ is also possible, which will simply reverse our choices of $\xi$ and $\eta$. Since the equation is symmetric, nothing would really change.)

Evaluating for these values gives:

$$4\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi d\eta}=0$$

which of course, is equivalent to the equation we want:

$$\frac{\partial ^2u}{\partial \xi d\eta}=0$$

Comment: Use \partial for partial derivatives.

Comment: Ahhh see that makes so much more sense I was so confused when the second order partial derivative looked like an expanded quadratic, very helpful thank you.